# How to make a function call with ng-checked : Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I need to display data when i checked on a checkbox(for example when i clicked on multiple checkbox i should get the data regarding all checkbox value)for this i have tried ng-checked and call the functions inside this directive but when i have write this in my code a very ridiculous thing happened with me,my system is getting hanged.so i have wrote ng-change for showing my code.

```
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-warning">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model= "fields" value="{{f.id}}" class="styled" id="function-{{f.id}}" ng-change="filter_fields(f.id); field_work_by_id(f.id);">
      <label for="function-{{f.id}}">{{f.name}}</label>
 </div>
```

In angular controller

```
   $scope.get_work_fields = function(){
        Data.getWorkFields().success(function (data) {
            $scope.fields = data;

        });
    };

    //where data in f getting from fields

    $scope.field_work_by_id = function($id){
        Data.fieldWorkById($id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.fieldswork = data;

        });
    };
```

In services:

```
this.getWorkFields = function ($data) {
    return $http.post(site_url + "User/User/getWorkFieldsData" , $data);
};

this.fieldWorkById = function ($data) {
    return $http.post(site_url + "User/User/fieldWorkByIdData/" + $data);
};
```

In codeigniter controller:

```
public function filterFieldsData($id){
    $rs = $this->user->filterFieldsData($id);
    if ($rs) {
        echo json_encode($rs);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '0', 'msg' => 'No Result Found'));
    }
}

public function fieldWorkByIdData($id){
    $rs = $this->user->fieldWorkByIdData($id);
    if ($rs) {
        echo json_encode($rs);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '0', 'msg' => 'No Result Found'));
    }
}
```

In model:

```
public function getWorkFieldsData(){
    $rs = $this->db->select('jb_work_field.id,jb_work_field.name')
                    ->from('jb_work_field')
                    ->where('jb_work_field.status','Active')
                    ->get()->result();
    return $rs;
}

public function fieldWorkByIdData($id){
    $rs = $this->db->select('jb_work_field.id,jb_work_field.name')
                    ->from('jb_work_field')
                    ->where('jb_work_field.status','Active')
                    ->where('jb_work_field.id',$id)
                    ->get()->result();
    return $rs;
}
```

So, please suggest me how can get the data after clicking on multiple checkbox.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the complete code, for example what is filter_fields(), field_work_by_id() and f?

Comment: @Marcus Höglund.. i have updated my code please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring functions in the NgChange directive, the functions needs to be in the current (angularjs) scope. In your case angularjs will not find any methods on the scope named `filter_fields` as they are part of the codeigniter controller. 
Try to refactor the code so you do angularjs all the way: create the filter methods in angularjs = check the custom filter section [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp) on how to do it.